# How to use .fbx file in android studio?

Tags: android, file, 3d, fbx

I need to implement 3D model in my app. I have .fbx file and I want to implement it. I tried with .obj file and it is working but I am not able to use .fbx file.

Can you please help me with .fbx file as I have already implemented .obj file but it doesn't give textures.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You may need to use Unity3d to import the ".fbx" file and build it to run in Android. Unity3d will generate ".apk" file.

Following link may help you.
http://www.goprogramming.space/unity-and-android-studio-integration/