# Is this possible to import Maya file into android?

Tags: android, maya

I want to use maya 3d model into my app,i searched everywhere but i am not getting anything.please help me.

Comment: Please  take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before asked

Comment: Which model format specifically? Maya supports a lot of export formats

Comment: hey if anyone dont know the answer so dont say this is not useful.

Comment: can i used fbx extention

Comment: You can use assimp library to load/convert fbx. google "assimp android"

Answer (score 0):

Android doesn't support Autodesk proprietary file formats such as Maya ASCII (**ma**) and Maya Binary (**mb**). But you can use common cross-platform 3D formats like OBJ or FBX.

[Rendering Maya animation on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7690595/rendering-maya-animation-on-android)

[How to use .fbx file in android studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36982198/how-to-use-fbx-file-in-android-studio)

Remember that can use only specified 3D formats on Android platform. Check what are those formats at official Android resource:

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/opengl.html